# Read Hex bits from encoded file and show it as an image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using JM reference software for encoding and decoding of video. What I want to do is to encode a video and then read it as hex file into matlab. Afterwards I want to show each frame as an image.

I know that each frame starts with "00 00 00 01" So what I have done is that I have found all indexes where this "00 00 00 01" string is located and then I read from one index to another convert it into an matrix and show it as an Image but image is empty.

Here is my code:

```
hexFileName = 'C:\Users\Safi\Desktop\Encoded.txt';
videoHexArray = importdata(hexFileName);
strFrameIndex = strfind(videoHexArray, '00 00 00 01');
%disp(videoHexArray);
videoHexString = char(videoHexArray);
OneFrame=videoHexString(76:6821);
disp(OneFrame);
imshow(str2num(OneFrame));
figure;
```

Comment: What is `str2num` supposed to do here? And why there is a `figure` command after `imshow`? You do not need it.

Comment: `str2num` is there because `imshow` expects an array and not a string . Yes we don't need figure command. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is `size(videoHexString)`? I think you are getting a vector for `OneFrame`.

Comment: 41963 is the size I am getting. Plus it has header I frame and p frames as well. I have encoded foreman video using JM reference software and using that file as an input

Comment: And you want to plot a vector to show an image? An image has a size such as `320x240` in each RGB layer and it includes `3` layers. You should figure out how to map your data to have an image structure, otherwise the `imshow` function cannot plot it.

Comment: Can you please give me a clue?. I am coding in matlab for the first time.

Comment: It only allows to attach an image

Comment: sorry try this one https://justpaste.it/

Comment: http://justpaste.it/pbp5

Answer (score 1):

If your input data looks like below, you need to get rid of line numbers and the raw data. Obviously you are reading this from a debugger or hexit software.

[image]

You can do this in MATLAB. Open the data using import data gui and select the important vectors:

[image]

You also have to get rid of the first line.

Now if you have your data in the following form:

[image]

in a `txt` file, you can read the hex values using `textread` function and proceed as follows:

```
 M=textread('test3.txt','%2c');
A = zeros(847,16);
 kk = 1;
for ii = 1:847
    for jj = 1:16
        A(ii,jj) = hex2dec(M(kk:kk+1));
        kk = kk + 1;
    end
end

imshow(A)
```

Because the output decimal data is already in range [0,255] you do not need to normalize. However you need to now how the data is structured. In the other words what is the size of the frame. For now it is 874x16 which obviously is not the right frame-size. To convert to a correct frame-size, you might use `reshape` function on the matrix `A`.

Comment: Yes I saved only the highlighted one in another file. I am using that file as an input. So this is not the problem

Comment: How can you say frame size is 874 * 16?

Comment: 874 is the number of lines in your file and 16 is the number of chars in each line. It is the way you should read the data. But the final image should have different frame-size. Also you can easily find it out if you are extracting these files from a video.

Comment: Frame size was 176x144 and currently I have tried a lot but unable to show IFrame or Pframe as an Image